# Is there any way to remove specific rule when building the RelNode using RelBuilder?

Tags: java, apache-calcite

I am building a RelNode using RelBuilder.

```
FrameworkConfig frameworkConfig = config().build();
 final RelBuilder builder = RelBuilder.create(frameworkConfig);
  RelNode root =
                 builder.scan("ITEM", "TEST")
                 .filter(
                         builder.equals(builder.field("ITEM_ID"), builder.literal("AM_TestItem_21Aug17_0614")))
                 .filter(
                        builder.equals(builder.field("OBJECT_TYPE"), builder.literal("Item")))
                 .build();

 PreparedStatement preparedStatement = RelRunners.run(root)
 preparedStatement.executeQuery()
```

```
    public static Frameworks.ConfigBuilder config() {
        CalciteSchema rootSchema1 = CalciteSchema.createRootSchema(true);
        rootSchema1 = rootSchema1.add("ITEM", new MySchema());
        // MySchema consists of Map of MyFilterableTable which extends AbstractTable and implements FilterableTable
        return Frameworks.newConfigBuilder().defaultSchema(rootSchema1.plus());
    }
```

scan method in MyFilterableTable 
`public Enumerable<Object[]> scan(DataContext root, List<RexNode> filters)`
gets merged filter string as [AND(=($0, 'AM_TestItem_21Aug17_0614'), =($3, 'Item'))]

I want separate entries of these filters and not merged one. 
I want planner to ignore the FilterMergeRule.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Used `root.getCluster().getPlanner().removeRule(FilterMergeRule.INSTANCE);` to ignore `FilterMergeRule` rule in optimization.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to selectively enable/disable rules when using the `RelBuilder` API and this is normal given that this API is meant only to create plans.

Moreover it is not a good idea to rely on the fact that the filters will not be merged since there is a high chance that in the future the merge that is currently done via `FilterMergeRule` could be done with the RelBuilder when there are two adjacent filter operators.

Nevertheless, inside the scan operation you could call `RelOptUtil#conjunctions` method which splits the filter into separate conjunctions which is more or less what you would like to obtain if I understand well your use-case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. RelOptUtil#conjunctions gave separate conditions decomposed by AND.